# Error: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'SignupComponent'

Tags: html, angular

I am building an angular project template for a hospital. I created signup and login pages and i wrote an Auth Service which stores the user data on the local storage. Everything, including the form validation, worked perfectly until i made reference to the service in html file after injecting the service into the .ts file. On my terminal, i am getting an ngtsc(2339) error which says 'property 'email' does not exist on type 'signupcomponent'. Where did i go wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Navigation starts-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/assets/images/logo-2.png" /><span> Med</span>ical</a
      >
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a
              class="nav-link"
              [routerLink]="['/login']"
              routerLinkActive="active"
              ariaCurrentWhenActive="page"
              >Have an exisiting account? Login</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Navigation Ends -->
  <video autoplay loop muted playsinline="playsinline">
    <source src="../../assets/videos/background-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <mat-card class="signUp-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title></mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <h3 class="center">Hi</h3>
      <p class="center">Please fill the form below to create your account.</p>
      <br />
      <form
        class="form"
        [formGroup]="registerForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
        novalidate
      >
        <mat-form-field class="form-full-width" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
          <input
            placeholder="Username..."
            matInput
            formControlName="uName"
            id="uName"
            type="text"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': submitted && f['uName'].errors }"
          />
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['uName'].errors?.['required']"
            >Username is required</mat-error
          >
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['uName'].errors?.['userNameNotAvailable']"
            >This username is not available.</mat-error
          >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="form-full-width" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Full name</mat-label>
          <input
            placeholder="First name..."
            matInput
            formControlName="fname"
            id="fname"
            type="text"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': submitted && f['fname'].errors }"
          />
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['fname'].errors?.['required']"
            >Full name is required</mat-error
          >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="form-full-width" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input
            placeholder="Email..."
            matInput
            formControlName="email"
            type="email"
            id="email"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': submitted && f['email'].errors }"
          />
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['email'].errors?.['required']"
            >Email is required.</mat-error
          >
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['email'].errors?.['email']"
            >Enter a valid email.</mat-error
          >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-full-width">
          <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            formControlName="password"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': submitted && f['password'].errors }"
          />
          <button
            mat-icon-button
            matSuffix
            (click)="hide = !hide"
            [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
            [attr.aria-pressed]="hide"
          >
            <mat-icon>{{ hide ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['password'].errors?.['required']"
            >Password is required.</mat-error
          >
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['password'].errors?.['invalidPassowrd']"
            >Password should have minimum 8 characters, at least 1 uppercase
            letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 number.</mat-error
          >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-full-width">
          <mat-label>Confirm password</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
            type="password"
            formControlName="cPassword"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-valid': submitted && f['cPassword'].errors }"
          />
          <button
            mat-icon-button
            matSuffix
            (click)="hide = !hide"
            [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
            [attr.aria-pressed]="hide"
          >
            <mat-icon>{{ hide ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['cPassword'].errors?.['required']"
            >Confirm the passowrd you entered.</mat-error
          >
          <mat-error *ngIf="f['cPassword'].errors?.['misMatch']"
            >Passowrds don't match.</mat-error
          >
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="center">
          <button mat-button type="submit" (click)="authService.register(email.value, password.value)">REGISTER</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>

<!-- Modal To Display Sign Up Success-->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="signUpSuccessModal"
  data-bs-backdrop="static"
  data-bs-keyboard="false"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="signUpSuccessModal"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="signUpSuccessModal">Success</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Congratulations. Your account has been successfully created. Kindly log
        in with your credentials.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Of Modal-->

<!-- Modal To Display Sign Up Failure-->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="signUpFailureModal"
  data-bs-backdrop="static"
  data-bs-keyboard="false"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="signUpFailureModal"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="signUpFailureModal">Oh-oh</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Failed. Your account was not successfully created. Plese check if you
        still have an active internet connection.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Of Modal-->
```

The .ts file:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormControl,
  AbstractControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { text } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { CustomvalidationService } from '../shared/services/customvalidation.service';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss'],
})
export class SignupComponent {
  hide = true;
  registerForm!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  dataset: any;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private customValidator: CustomvalidationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        fname: ['', Validators.required],
        uName: [
          '',
          [Validators.required],
          this.customValidator.userNameValidator.bind(this.customValidator),
        ],
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: [
          '',
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            this.customValidator.patternValidator(),
          ]),
        ],
        cPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },
      {
        validator: this.customValidator.mustMatch('pasword', 'cPassword'),
      }
    );

    // // script for passowrd and confrim password toggle
    // const togglePassword = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
    // const toggleConfirmPassword = document.querySelector('#toggleConfirmPass');
    // const password = document.querySelector('#passowrd');
    // const cPassword = document.querySelector('cPassword');

    // togglePassword?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //   //toggle the type attribute for password
    //   const type =
    //     password?.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    //   password?.setAttribute('type', type);

    //   //toggle the eye
    //   password?.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
    // });

    // toggleConfirmPassword?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //   //toggle the type attribute for password
    //   const type =
    //     cPassword?.getAttribute('type') === 'cPassword' ? 'text' : 'cPassword';
    //   cPassword?.setAttribute('type', type);

    //   //toggle the eye
    //   cPassword?.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
    // });
  }

  get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.registerForm.controls;
  }

  openModal() {
    const openEls: any = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-target]');
    const isVisible = 'modal';
    for (const el of openEls) {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const signUpSuccessModal = this.dataset.open;
        document.getElementById(signUpSuccessModal)?.classList.add(isVisible);
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.registerForm.valid) {
      this.openModal();
      console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    } else {
      console.error();
    }
  }
}
```

The auth service file:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Auth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  sendEmailVerification,
  User,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  UserData: any;

  constructor(
    private auth: Auth,
    private router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user: any) => {
      if (user) {
        this.UserData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.UserData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      }
    });
  }
  // Getting User
  // Getting the authenticated user from firebase
  getAuthFire() {
    return this.auth.currentUser;
  }

  // Getting the authenticated user from the local storage
  getAuthLocal() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const user = JSON.parse(token as string);
    return user;
  }

  // Checking whether User is logged in or not
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const user = JSON.parse(token as string);
    return user !== null ? true : false;
  }

  // Register Method.
  async register(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      this.UserData = result.user;
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        /* Call the sendVerificationMail() function when a new user signs up and returns promise*/
        this.sendEmailVerification();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      window.alert(error.message);
    }
  }

  //Login Method
  async login(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      this.UserData = result.user;
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/main']);
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      window.alert(err.message);
    }
  }

  //Logging out
  async logOut() {
    await signOut(this.auth).then(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']));
  }

  //Sending Password Reset Email In Case User Forgets Password
  async sendPasswordResetEmails(email: string) {
    sendPasswordResetEmail(this.auth, email)
      .then(() => {
        window.alert(
          'A password reset email have been sent to the email you provided. \nKindly check your inbox or your spam folder. '
        );
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }

  // Sending Email Verification
  sendEmailVerification() {
    return sendEmailVerification(this.auth.currentUser as User);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line states the error? `<button mat-button type="submit" (click)="authService.register(email.value, password.value)">REGISTER</button>`? It seems the compilation error mentioned that the `email` variable is not defined.

Comment: The `email` and `password` are controls from your form, they're not direct members of your class. So you have a getter for form control as `f` which you are referrencing in your template and you can use it as param in your method call too: instad of `email.value` and `password.value` try `f.email.value` and `f.password.value`, or `f['email'].value` and `f['password'].value`

Comment: @MishaMashina Thanks a lot. That solution did wonders for me. i used the f['email'].value and f['password'].value and it cleared every error.

Comment: @MishaMashina Thanks. I used the `f['email'].value` and `f['password'].value` and it cleared every error.